# Recognize added customer to automatically issue & send invoice

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm new to use VBA and I counter this that I couldn't find solution, I have 3 sheets in workbook, first one customer sheet that I update daily to add new customers, 2nd sheet is invoice the 3rd one is record of invoices, I completed all the workflow of issuing & sending emails as PDF invoices, and store the records in my log.  I simply looking to make macro to recognise I added customer with unique invoice number in sheet1, then compare with the history log last row, if they are not matching create new invoice for this customer and send it to them, if matching don't do anything.

This is my macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmailPDF()

Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim EItem As Object
Set EItem = EApp.createItem(0)

Dim CompanyID As String
Dim CompanyName As String
Dim ContractedTrainees As String
Dim InvoiceNo As String
Dim CompanyCoordName As String
Dim CompanyCoordEmail As String
Dim CompanyCoordEmail As String
Dim CompanyCoordEmail As String
Dim ContractStart As Date
Dim ContractEnd As Date
Dim ContractEnd As Date
Dim ContractEnd As Date
Dim ContractPrice As Currency
Dim Discount As String
Dim DiscountAmnt As String
Dim FinalPrice As String
Dim VAT As String
Dim TaxAmount As String
Dim TotalPrice As String
Dim Descripition As String
Dim Subtotal As String
Dim Taxes As String
Dim FinalTotal As String
Dim Total As Currency
Dim Path As String
Dim FName As String
Dim nextrec As Range

CompanyID = Sheet2.Range("C6")
CompanyName = Sheet2.Range("C7")
ContractedTrainees = Sheet2.Range("A20")
InvoiceNo = Sheet2.Range("D32")
CompanyCoordName = Sheet2.Range("C9")
CompanyCoordEmail = Sheet2.Range("C10")
ContractStart = Sheet2.Range("F24")
ContractEnd = Sheet2.Range("B24")
ContractPrice = Sheet2.Range("C20")
Discount = Sheet2.Range("D20")
Total = Sheet2.Range("D27")
Path = "C:\Users\owaism\OneDrive\P1\Project Management\Sales\Invoice\Invoices\"
FName = CompanyID & " - " & InvoiceNo

Sheet2.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:=Path & FName

Set nextrec = Sheet4.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

nextrec = CompanyID
nextrec.Offset(0, 1) = CompanyName
nextrec.Offset(0, 2) = ContractedTrainees
nextrec.Offset(0, 3) = InvoiceNo
nextrec.Offset(0, 4) = CompanyCoordName
nextrec.Offset(0, 5) = CompanyCoordEmail
nextrec.Offset(0, 6) = ContractStart
nextrec.Offset(0, 7) = ContractEnd
nextrec.Offset(0, 8) = ContractPrice
nextrec.Offset(0, 9) = Discount
nextrec.Offset(0, 10) = Total

Sheet4.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=nextrec.Offset(0, 12), Address:=Path & FName & ".xlsx"

Sheet4.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=nextrec.Offset(0, 11), Address:=Path & FName & ".pdf"


With EItem

.To = Range("C10")
.Subject = "Invoice No: " & InvoiceNo
.body = "Please find Invoice attached."
.Attachments.Add (Path & FName & ".pdf")
.Send

End With

Sheet2.Range("C6").ClearContents

Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Do a `worksheet_change` on sheet1 that loops sheet3 for invoice number. If not found, run your macro.

Comment: Why do you have some variables dimensioned three times? `Dim CompanyCoordEmail As String`, 
`Dim CompanyCoordEmail As String`, 
`Dim CompanyCoordEmail As String`